# Period, метод normalized(), а что же дни?

Tags: java, время

Метод normalized() из библиотеки java.time.Period нормализирует только месяцы и годы: 1 year 13 months => 2 year 1 months; но не нормализирует дни: если было 40 дней, то не станет 1 месяц и 10 дней. Неужели с днями нужно будет работать только в ручную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, что, например, `14 месяцев`, это `1 год + 2 месяца.` Если мы прибавим этот период к любой дате, например `2017-10-02`, оба варианта, мы получим одинаковый результат - `2018-12-02`. Потому что *n*-й день месяца через любое количество месяцев останется *n*-м днем месяца.

С днями месяца это не работает. Например, `60 дней` от Нового года могут дать как 2 полных месяца `(31 + 29)`, так и два полных месяца и один день `(31 + 28 + 1)`. Поэтому интервал длиной в 60 дней нельзя однозначно нормализовать в месяцы без привязки к конкретной дате.

Comment: В лунных календарях 1 год=13 месяцам :)

Comment: Ну `Period`-то явно говорит, что он про ISO-8601 календарь. )